# send a variable to another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to send a variable to another function? like for this example:

```
function test2(){
    $('body').append(lol);
}

function test1(){
    var lol = "test";
    test2();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either prepare an argument for `test2()`:

```
function test2(elem)
{
    $('body').append(elem);
}

function test1()
{
    var lol = "test";
    test2(lol);
}
```

Or declare `lol` outside of the functions so it's available to both..

```
var lol;

function test2()
{
    $('body').append(lol);
}

function test1()
{
    lol = "test";
    test2();
}
```

Comment: No worries! Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Do you simply mean "how do I pass a parameter into a function"? If so, then:

```
function test2(someParam){
    $('body').append(someParam);
}

function test1(){
    var lol = "test";
    test2(lol);
}
```

You can give a function any number of parameters (in this case there is just the one; `someParam`). When you call the function, you can then pass in a value (in this case, we pass in the variable `lol`). You could, for example, pass in a string:

`test2('randomString');`

This would append that string to the `body`, instead of the value of the variable.